# viewDidLayoutSubviews & UIApplicationDidBecomeActive notification

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload, uiapplication, viewdidlayoutsubviews

In my `viewDidLoad`, I add code to follow `UIApplication.didBecomeActive` notification as follows:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(ViewController.applicationDidBecomeActive),
                                       name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
                                       object: UIApplication.shared)
```

The question is whether it is a given that once the notification is subscribed in `viewDidLoad`, the notification callback will not fire before `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called? It so happens on all my iOS devices across all iOS versions but it seems to be the source of bug if this is not true. Trying to figure out sources of all unreproducible bugs, not sure if this can be one of them.

Comment: If you are using `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` incorrectly, then sure, it could be a source of "bugs" in your app. Without providing any information about what you're doing, no other answer could be offered.

Comment: I just wanted to know what is supposed to be the order of calls -- viewDidLoad, viewDidLayoutSubviews, and UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification. Is there a supposed order that is followed or UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification can be called even before viewDidLoad?

Comment: You probably want to read up on Application and Controller lifecycles. Search for `UIApplication lifecycle` and `UIViewController lifecycle`. It will help you understand when events happen, as well as what you should (and should not) do during each step.